# Unable to receive emails from gmail addresses on my custom domain

Tags: email, apache-http-server, gmail, webserver

I have created a custom email address for my domain `contact@mydomain.com` and  tried to send an email from `myaddress@gmail.com` to `contact@mydomain.com` but I did not receive anything in my inbox.

Then, I sent an email from `contact@mydomain.com` to `myaddress@gmail.com` and it showed up in my Gmail inbox. When I replied to that email, the reply did not appear in the inbox of `contact@mydomain.com`.

The problem only occurs with Gmail addresses. I could receive the emails for twitter and other services. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What are you using to receive mail?

Comment: @Paul I am not exactly sure but it is an email client on my hosting account. It goes by the name "Horde".

Comment: Have you waited enough to receive bounce messages? (reports via email to sender of the original message about delivery problems)  AFAIR sendmail (not gmail) sends "warning" after 4 hours and "final error" after 5 days.

Comment: You will need to contact your mail service provider.